# How to load an already saved plot and plot again on top of it(In matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, plot, graph

I have done a plot and saved it in a file. Now I want to draw something on it by loading the existing plot. Is it possible to do the same?

Comment: What did you saved in a file? The plot picture or the plot data? If saved the plot data you can do that.

Comment: Well, you save the data and the script and run it again. Other approaches don't make much sense.

Comment: You _can_ pickle the figure, save the pickle, reload and keep drawing.  Some things will be broken however, and it really is better to just save the underlying data and rerun a script as @JohanC says above.